# SVG Optimizing- Multiple Paths vs. Complex Compound Shapes

Tags: svg

When creating SVGs in an editor, like Illustrator or Inkscape, I am curious as to the best final way to output the artwork.

For instance, let's say I have a fairly complex svg, perhaps a bunch of random logo shapes.  All the logos have the same fill color, so naturally I would want to merge all the logo shapes into one condensed compound path.

Logic tells me that the file size would be smaller if the SVG output is one large path containing all the coordinate data for the whole image.  (im thinking similar to a minified js file for example).

I am wondering though, if the SVG actually performs better this way? or if each shape in my file should remain as separate (smaller) paths?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other browsers, but very long SVG path drawing (10,000+ nodes) is slow in older webkit/blink browsers, but has been improved significantly in Safari 6/recent Chrome/iOS7.